# How to replace multiples in this array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
array = ['blue', 'red', 'green', 'green', 'red', 'blue', 'black', 'blue']
```

...the output I'm trying to achieve would result in

```
output = ['blue x3', 'red x2', 'green x2', 'black']
```

I'm having a hard time figuring out the most effective way to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try anything yet? You're having trouble with the "most effective" way or getting it to work at all? Show what you've tried or people may post the exact method you're using.

Comment: dont worry about the most effective way, just try some way

Comment: yea, I tried finding the indexOf the first value and then replacing that value but it doesn't account for mutiple values unless i recurse and that didn't seem like the right way and there had to be a better approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 var array = ['blue', 'red', 'green', 'green', 'red', 'blue', 'black', 'blue'] 

 var hash = {};
 for( var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i){
     hash[array[i]] = (!hash.hasOwnProperty(array[i]) ? 1 : hash[array[i]]+1);
 }

 var output = [];
 for(var key in hash){
     output.push( key + (hash[key]>1 ? (" x"+hash[key]):"") );
 }
 console.log( output ); //["blue x3", "red x2", "green x2", "black"]
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/xRMAh/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr =  ['blue', 'red', 'green', 'green', 'red', 'blue', 'black', 'blue'];

var group = {};
for (var i = arr.length; --i >= 0;) {
  var value = arr[i];
  group[value] = 1 - -(group[value] | 0);
}
var result = [];
for (e in group) { 
  result.push(e + ' x' + group[e]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a cheesy solution I came up with quickly;

```
var array = ['blue', 'red', 'green', 'green', 'red', 'blue', 'black', 'blue'],
    output = [], temp = {}, i;

// loop through array and count the values
array.forEach(function(a){
    temp[a] = temp[a] ? temp[a]+1 : 1;
});

// loop though temp and add "xN" to the values
for(i in temp){
    output.push(i + (temp[i] > 1 ? ' x'+temp[i] : ''));
}

console.log(output);
```

Note: [`.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) doesn't work in IE 8 (or lower).

Answer (score 0):

```
// You can use an object to group strings
var colourGroups = {};
var array = ['blue', 'red', 'green', 'green', 'red', 'blue', 'black', 'blue'];

// loop and group each colour. 
array.forEach(function(colourName) {

    if (colourGroups[colourName] )
        // increment the count
        colourGroups[colourName]++;
    else
        //initialize the property with 1
        colourGroups[colourName] = 1;

});    


// display results
var results = [];

for(var prop in colourGroups) {
    var colourCountStats = prop + " x " + colourGroups[prop];
    results.push(colourCountStats );
}

console.log(results);
document.write(results);​
```

JS Fiddle Example: http://jsfiddle.net/peterf/J7EUc/